# Getting error while implementing a simple redux store counter implementation in Angular

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I am trying to learn how to implement redux in angular app. I followed 
  https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/docs/store

I followed all steps provided but getting this error

> Argument of type '"counter"' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: IAppState) => number'.

I am not able to understand what I missed.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { MileStoneService } from './milestone.service';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import {  INCREMENT ,DECREMENT ,RESET} from './app.actions'; // <- New    
import { MileStoneModel } from "app/MileStoneModel";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
interface IAppState {
  counter: number;
  //mileStones: MileStoneModel[]
}

export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  title = 'app';
  counter$: Observable<number>;
 readonly mileStones$: Observable<MileStoneModel>;

 constructor(private store: Store<IAppState>  , private _service: MileStoneService ) {
     // HERE IS THE ERROR
        this.counter$ = this.store.select<number>('counter');
    }

    increment(){
        this.store.dispatch({ type: INCREMENT });
    }

    decrement(){
        this.store.dispatch({ type: DECREMENT });
    }

    reset(){
        this.store.dispatch({ type: RESET });
    }

}
```

App module class

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MileStoneService } from './milestone.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Http,HttpModule, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';


import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { counterReducer } from "app/app.actions";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule  , HttpModule ,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ counter: counterReducer }) ,
    !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : [],

  ],
  providers: [ MileStoneService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 


}
```

Reducer function

```
export const INCREMENT  = '[Counter] Increment';
export const DECREMENT  = '[Counter] Decrement';
export const RESET      = '[Counter] Reset';

export function counterReducer(state: number = 0, action: Action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case INCREMENT:
            return state + 1;

        case DECREMENT:
            return state - 1;

        case RESET:
            return 0;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error

Comment: @RahulSingh : Argument of type '"counter"' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: IAppState) => number'.

Comment: can you post your reducer

Comment: try using this in constructor `this.counter$ = store.select('counter');`

Comment: @RahulSingh added reducer and also tried  this.counter$ = store.select('counter');  . Get this error -- >> Decorators are not valid here.

Comment: why are you using the constants like this `export const INCREMENT  = '[Counter] Increment';` shoudn't it be  like `export const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT';` . Also have the interface above the `@component `decorator and then try . if you want a working exampole of the following example i have a link too

Comment: @RahulSingh : As mentioned I am very new to this redux stuff so I followed @nfrx/platform git link to start learning it  .  The link I refer to start https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/docs/store   . In this  documentation it is done like this so start following it .  I assumed that it should work as it .

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx) this is my repo and has the same working example above . you can open the src to view source code . make the changes i mentioned it should work

Comment: @RahulSingh :  Thanks for the link . I managed to look what I did wrong in my code after looking to your link provided .

Comment: did it work out ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150721/discussion-between-yashveer-singh-and-rahul-singh).